# Android: Avoiding duplicate fragment classes for Honeycomb and Compatibility Library

Tags: android, compatibility, code-reuse, fragment

Is it possible to have one fragment Java class used both for 2.x and 3.x Android versions?

Now I don't see it possible, which is rather unfortunate because in such a case I have to develop two 99% identical fragment classes - one for Honeycomb, and another for pre-Honeycomb devices using Android Compatibility Library.

I think it would be hugely beneficial to have some way to reuse the same Java class for both cases. Even more, I thought code reuse was a major purpose in using ACL...

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: One small additional note to my question: now it seems the only way to reuse code is by creating custom views - and not fragments ...

Comment: i don't get your point ... i'm using one fragment classes and different layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to have one fragment Java class used both for 2.x and 3.x Android versions?

Sure. Just inherit from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. The fragment will then work on all versions of Android from 1.6 onwards.

Comment: I mark this as the answer because... well it answers the question.

But now I see that I omitted an important part of the question - I wanted to avoid using ACL on Honeycomb! In short, I thought about making a fragment class that would "be part of" ACL on pre-3.x, and at the same time "part of" Honeycomb SDK itself on 3.x, which is of course impossible.

Thanks for helping me to see the problem clearly :)